# Change cell height when navigation bar becomes hidden

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UICollectionViewController with cells that represent the screen's view.  I do this to create a custom tab bar that changes to a different cell when a cell on the tab bar is selected.

I think that I need to change the cell height when the nav bar hides, but I am not sure how to do that or if this setup is "bad practice."

Here are all of my constraints(`menuBar` is the white toolbar at the bottom):

```
view.addSubview(menuBar)
view.addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|[v0]|", views: menuBar)
view.addConstraintsWithFormat("V:[v0(44)]", views: menuBar)
menuBar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

collectionView?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 44, 0)
collectionView?.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 44, 0)
```

Here I set the size for each item:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height - 44)
}
```

Because of this line in my code

```
navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
```

the nav bar hides properly, but I am left with this result(the blue is a cell):

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

Comment: I think you need to add `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false` into your view controller's `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: @MoeAbdul-Hameed I just noticed my status bar background was disappearing, and you solved that issue! but unfortunately, the white space is still there, except that the status bar color is correct.

Comment: @defoification This is a lay out issue. Can you post the layout constraints of your collection view please?

Comment: @FangmingNing I think I got them all.  See my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a white space because you are asking your collection view to have a padding between the bottom of content to the button of collection view. Here are your codes to do that.

```
collectionView?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 44, 0)
collectionView?.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 44, 0)
```

When you try to set `hidesBarsOnSwipe` to be true, it's very important to make sure that your collection view has correct constraint against its surroundings because when navigation bar is hidden, your collection view actually use the space of navigation bar. So first, make sure to set `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` of your view controller to false. Then, make sure that the top and bottom constraints of your collection view is connected between your collection view and top & button layout guide like this

[image]

Finally, remove the content insets code, that two lines of code to have a button padding of 44.

Comment: Since I am not using IB, what would superview be?  Would I do something like `collectionView?.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview).isActive = true`

Comment: @defoification Try this `collectionView?.topAnchor.constraint( equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true`

Comment: That won't work since I have the custom toolbar at the bottom-- I need a way to set the anchor to the top of the menubar.  Do you know a method to achieve this?

Comment: @defoification Use similar syntax. Now you want the botto of your collecrionView to stick together with menubar. So your code should be `collectionView?.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: menubar.topAnchor).isActive = true`

Comment: :( it's not working.  I tried this earlier and it crashed my program saying that is illegal, but now the menubar doesn't appear.  I think I need to either change the cell size according to dragging, or setup up my entire view differently.

Comment: @defoification If you use a tab bar instead of a menubar, it will make life way easier because your current view controller does not own the tab bar so you can safely add bottom anchor to bottom layout guide